# But it's basically it(?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, listening

I heard [[30:35-30:47] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=1835) as follows;

> "This is the ghost town of Two Guns. There's not much to see here
> anymore. There's this old abandoned gas station, and then few old
> buildings(>fuel building's?) out there as well. But **it's basically
> it(?)**.”

I wonder what the meaning of '**it's basically it.**' is in the above context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, that's basically it.

That means that what he just described is all that is there.

Comment: Thank you very much.